# Get rgb value of image when user clicked on image

Tags: android

I am creating a map application. I need to get **RGB** value of image when user clicked on image.
Image is in `ImageView`.

Please help.

Comment: -1 for no research effort and nothing tried on your own.

Comment: @alextsc he joined today only to SO. He need to go thru http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

```
int ColorCode = imageView.getDrawingCache().getPixel(x, y);
```

//here x,y are coordinates

here is an [link](http://www.41post.com/3719/programming/android-how-to-return-rgb-values-from-an-image-file)

Comment: Did you check my link that I provided?

Comment: i checked....the code is fine but not for my purpose.in my application user click on a image the rgb value of that particular pixel is needed to switch case.(no fixed position and color)

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();  
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(xCordinate,yCordinate);  
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);  
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);  
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
```