# android get pixel data from onPreviewFrame convert to a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, getpixel

how do i use 
    onPreviewFrame (byte[] data, Camera camera)
 inorder to getPixel(int x, int y). I want to change the frame into a bitMap is that possible? I am using onPreviewFrame because I want to getPixel data every second, so it would be too long to get the picture.

Comment: will this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9701011/1012284

Comment: ya it does a little. it is more i dont know how to get the image from the onPreviewFrame, like if i import the image i can do all my calculations, but i dont know how to get the image from that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    byte[] baos = convertYuvToJpeg(data, camera);
    if (baos != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Tool.loadBitmap(baos);
    }
}

public byte[] convertYuvToJpeg(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    try {
        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21,
                camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width,
                camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height,
                null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0,
                camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width,
                camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height);
        //set quality
        int quality = 100;
        image.compressToJpeg(rect, quality, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: java is slowly to convert image format,
you can use libuv to speed up